# need an image to appear constantly sliding jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, appendto

trying to have the appearance of an image sliding from left to right continuously repeating

Tried a number of ways to do this, but am currently trying it with two images, then appending one to the front of the other when it appears outside of focus, I'm close but where am I going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Antifaith/b3pdn/ - version 1

http://jsfiddle.net/b3pdn/2/ - version 2

Comment: Some HTML with fully-qualified image paths (http://...) would be helpful to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my jQuery Plugin zip. which reads the data from XML and create a slider from right to left.

Hope this example will help you in creating the same left to right.

Note the below example is created by me only. without any copyright. and very small sized. you can customize and optimize the code if you need.

[Download Plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kkiey9zp6qbw8am/6MzxlmPwXk)

**EDIT:**

I have gone through your both versions of fiddle but it seems that you have used wrong HTML and style for animating your image.

Following are the issues

1. your both images are of different width
2. you have uses `position:absolute` without `left` and `top` position.
3. you have used `float:left` and `float:right` to parent and child divs.
4. width to any image is not given therefore `float:left` is of no use.

I think you should try a correct example as per my plugin which i have placed on DropBox. it will give you the idea to create an example. I m trying at my end to generate the same. Once the functionality is ready i will upload it here for you to review.

Comment: did'nt use it, but could be useful, still looking for a solution to this problem

Comment: yeah it was a mess so I tried a different approach, only problem now is that I need to eliminate the black spaces between slides, so it appears as one continuous image http://jsfiddle.net/Antifaith/tqBMQ/